# How can I put ax like a plot and no subplot with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

this is the code:

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


f = lambda x: pow(x, 3) / (pow(x, 2) - x - 6)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(-15.0, 15.0, 1000)
plt.axis([x[0], x[-1], -15.0, 15.0])
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ticks = []
for i in range(-15, 16, 5):
    ticks.append(i)
ticks.remove(0)
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
plt.plot(x, f(x), color='b', linestyle='-', lw=1.5)
plt.plot(x, x + 1.0, color='b', linestyle='--', lw=1.5)
plt.legend([r'$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2-x-6}$', r'$y=x+1$'], loc='lower right')
plt.title('Discontinuous Function')
plt.grid('on')
plt.show()
```

I want to set ax like a plot, not like a subplots. How can I change it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what "like a plot" means?

Comment: Do you want an ax to work like a pyplot instead of a subplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can you not change

```
plt.plot(x, f(x), color='b', linestyle='-', lw=1.5)
plt.plot(x, x + 1.0, color='b', linestyle='--', lw=1.5)
plt.legend([r'$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2-x-6}$', r'$y=x+1$'], loc='lower right')
plt.title('Discontinuous Function')
plt.grid('on')
```

to

```
ax.plot(x, f(x), color='b', linestyle='-', lw=1.5)
ax.plot(x, x + 1.0, color='b', linestyle='--', lw=1.5)
ax.legend([r'$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2-x-6}$', r'$y=x+1$'], loc='lower right')
ax.set_title('Discontinuous Function') # notice this one changed to set_title
ax.grid()
plt.show() # keep this one plt.
```

?  Otherwise, I'm not quite sure what your question is asking.  Where exactly is the problem? Do you have a traceback?

Comment: I don't understand very well, but the only way to put the axes in the center of the plot is using ax, but your solution and my code not draw the plot in whole window, it draws it in a subplot. I suppose it is my problem because I don't understand the main matplotlib documentation because I'm not english. Thanks

Comment: I mean, I don't want 
fig, ax = plt.subplots() I want plot

Comment: Why do you not want to use fig, ax? In order to have the axes go through the center of the plot and have the tick marks on them, using `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` is the best way.  If you just want a horizontal and vertical line going through (0, 0), that can be done easily, but to get the tick marks on those lines, use `plt.subplots()`.

Comment: Additionally, `fig, ax = plt.subplots(); ax.plot()` gives the same result as `plt.plot()`, but you have more control over the plot when you break up the `plt` into `fig` and `ax`.

Comment: plt.xlabel and plt.ylabel is the solution you are looking for, I think